# Collection visibility and status filters are deprecated, what should be used instead?

Tags: php, magento, collections, filter, deprecated

The `addVisibleFilterToCollection()` and `addSaleableFilterToCollection()` methods of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status` are annotated with @deprecated, but there is no instruction as to what approach to use instead. Code within Magento's core is still using those methods, ref `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer::prepareProductCollection()`.

What approach should be used decorating the collection with the correct visibility/salable filters?

Answer (score 4):

For **Visibility** there is (from Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer::prepareProductCollection()):

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);
```

Which sets the CATALOG and BOTH filters to the collection.

For **Status** it appears a bit strange but still makes sense.
In _initSelect in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php
The following is done:

```
$this->getSelect()
            ->from(array(self::MAIN_TABLE_ALIAS => $this->getEntity()->getFlatTableName()), null)
            ->columns(array('status' => new Zend_Db_Expr(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)));
```

This code is executed when doing the

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
```

So basically the status ENABLED is already checked when doing the

```
$category->getProductCollection()
```

Or similar product collection calls.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried common approach :

```
addAttributeToFilter('visibility',Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)

addAttributeToFilter('status',1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at line 66

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Visibility.php
```

You will see the deprecated call is commented out  and replaced with

```
$collection->setVisibility($this->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
```

Here is how I use it my refactor

```
$this->_itemCollection->setVisibility($this->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
// Deprecated: Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($this->_itemCollection);
```

If you want more information on deprecated functions, take a look here: http://freegento.com/doc/dc/d5b/_visibility_8php-source.html